# Stopping subprocess ran by exec.command in golang

Tags: linux, bash, docker, go

This might seems like a similar question roaming around on the internet but it not as I didn't find any similar, so asking here.

The thing is, I have a go program named `abc.go` which contains two functions which are to run and stop `someScript.sh` script. Run() and stop() are being called at API hit. I am running this `abc.go` file using command `sudo go run abc.go someFolder/someScript.sh`, while passing `someScript.sh` path as argument. In`stop()`, I am saving the process-groupID and then killing the whole process-group.

But when I call run and then stop functions, it gives me this output

```
pid=5844 duration=13.667µs err=exec: already started
```

and doesn't actually stop the running docker container (I am checking using `docker container ls -a` ).

The someScript.sh file is:

```
#!/bin/bash
docker container run --rm --name someContainerName nginx
```

The abc.go file is:

```
func Run(){
    someVar= true
    execCMD = exec.Command("/bin/sh", "-c", commandFromTerminal)
    output, err = execCMD.CombinedOutput()
    fmt.Println("Output()=", bp.Output())
    someVar= false
}

func Stop(){
    execCMD.SysProcAttr = &syscall.SysProcAttr{Setpgid: true}
    start := time.Now()
    syscall.Kill(-execCMD.Process.Pid, syscall.SIGKILL)
    err := execCMD.Run()
    fmt.Printf("pid=%d duration=%s err=%s\n", execCMD.Process.Pid, time.Since(start), 
    err)
}
```

As per my understanding, it seems like docker command which is written in `someScript.sh`, didn't run the docker container as a subchild/grandchild of /bin/bash but rather ran it as a separate process which the code in my `stop()` is unable to actaully stop it

Below is the flow diagram which is according to my understanding where i think on calling `abc.go`, it internally calling /bin/bash, then running sudo as its child, further sudo has a subchildsomeScript.sh. And finally the docker, which is not running as any child/subchild of the above hierarchy, but as a different process.

My question finally is, how to stop this docker container on calling `stop()`. Or how to make this docker container run as a subchild of the hierarchy so that I can kill it using process-groupID method which I have used above.

PS: I have also tried

```
err := execCMD.Process.Kill()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    execCMD.Process.Release()
```

but it too didn't help.

[image]

Comment: In addition to what Peter explained: Do not use go run for such stuff.

Comment: Then what else I should use? "go install"? I did some hands dirty on it but it go install gives error when I pass the script path as argument saying "named files must be .go files:"

Comment: Use go build. Or at the very least if you think go build is unbearable: use `go run .`.

Comment: "go build" also shows the same error which I mentioned in the above comment ans doesn't let me pass .sh file as argument

Answer (score 0):

`docker` is just a client for the docker daemon. `docker run` simply sends a few HTTP requests to the daemon, and the daemon sets up the container and executes it.

So `docker run` is a grandchild of your Go program, but the nginx processes are descendants of the Docker daemon, and entirely unrelated to your Go program. Mind you, the docker daemon can even be on a different machine, in principle at least.

That being said,

1. Assigning SysProcAttr after a process has been started has no effect.
2. You're calling Run in Stop (very suspicious) and you cannot Run a process that has already been started, even after it terminated.
3. Sending SIGKILL gives `docker run` no chance to terminate the container. After fixing the other errors, it's possible that the docker daemon takes care of the cleanup due to the --rm flag (I forget how this works, exactly). If not, send SIGTERM instead.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but seems like after working on step 2(deleting calling run in stop function) didn't solve the issue. Nor SIGTERM is doing the work. Any other pointer, Peter?